# "Ich schaue hinein"

Tags: style, grammaticality

> Ich schaue ins Küchenfenster hinein, wo meine Mutter abwäscht.

Can I leave the "hinein" here or remove it? Any alternative for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatikalisch ist beides korrekt.

Allerdings ist der Bezug des "wo" falsch; denn die Mutter arbeitet nicht "im Küchenfenster", sondern "in der Küche".

Also hiesse es besser:

> Ich schaue durchs Fenster in die Küche [hinein], wo meine Mutter arbeitet.

oder

> Ich schaue ins Küchenfenster [hinein], und sehe meine Mutter [dort] arbeiten.

Das "dort" ist nur in Ordnung, wenn das "hinein" auch vorhanden ist, da sich das "dort" sonst wieder auf das "Küchenfenster" bezöge. Dagegen passt das "hinein" auch ohne "dort".

Comment: Even with *"hinein"* the *"dort"* (like *"wo"*) refers to the window amd mot to the kitchen in your second example. I would not put it there, even more so as it does not add much to the meaning.

Comment: @Takkat: Fair enough, however for the 2nd example one good argue that in the the "dort" referred to what "hinein" referred to.

Comment: wenn man "ins" mit "durchs" ersetzt, passt's IMO wieder.